# How to check checkbox if radio button is checked

Tags: java, android, checkbox, radio-button

I have a dialog. I wanted to change checked attributes but I couldn't. I want to check checkbox if radio button is checked.

It is activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="336dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is activity_dialog.xml which provides my custom dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/singleA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="tytClick"
            android:text="TYT" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearTYT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/multi1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="Maths" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/multi2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="Turkish"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/multi3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="English" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/singleB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="aytClick"
            android:text="AYT" />

    </RadioGroup>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And is MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final Context context = this;
Button start;
TextView textView;
CheckBox multi1, multi2,multi3;
RadioButton singleA, singleB;
LinearLayout linearTYT;
RadioGroup radioGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = findViewById(R.id.start);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    multi1 = findViewById(R.id.multi1);
    multi2 = findViewById(R.id.multi2);
    multi3 = findViewById(R.id.multi3);
    singleA = findViewById(R.id.singleA);
    singleB = findViewById(R.id.singleB);
    linearTYT = findViewById(R.id.linearTYT);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Choose");

            dialog.show();

        }

    });
    if (singleA.isChecked()) {
        multi1.setChecked(true);
        multi2.setChecked(true);
        multi3.setChecked(true);
        linearTYT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        multi1.setChecked(false);
        multi2.setChecked(false);
        multi3.setChecked(false);
        linearTYT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}}
```

I also tried to View.GONE the Linear Layout below of the Radio Button but it crashed. 
I think I can't change the view of dialog after appearing it. Or I couldn't do right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Seems like you are a beginner. I am providing the solution but some modifications might be needed for the perfect functioning.

You need to modify your OnClickListener.

First of all, you are using your activity_dialog.class (Which I believe to be `activity_dialog.xml`) in a dialog. So, you simply can't get it's views through `findViewById` method of the Activity Class. There is a `setOnCheckChangeListener` method for achieving what you want. It is similar to `Button.setOnClickListener()`.

The OnClickListener -

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Choose");
            dialog.show();
            multi1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.multi1);
            multi2 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.multi2);
            multi3 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.multi3);
            singleA = dialog.findViewById(R.id.singleA);
            singleB = dialog.findViewById(R.id.singleB);
            singleA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        multi1.setChecked(true);
                        multi2.setChecked(true);
                        multi3.setChecked(true);
                    }else{
                        multi1.setChecked(false);
                        multi2.setChecked(false);
                        multi3.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            singleB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        multi1.setChecked(false);
                        multi2.setChecked(false);
                        multi3.setChecked(false);
                    }else{
                        multi1.setChecked(true);
                        multi2.setChecked(true);
                        multi3.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

Some Tweaks will be needed as per your needs. Good Luck!!